# Share Option for PNGs

Tags: java, android, bitmap, png, share

I am trying to implement a share option for png pictures in my app, but I have been getting a TransactionTooLargeException. What I did: I added code to compress my Bitmap, but I still get the exception. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
    public void sharePicture(MenuItem shareItem) {
    MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
    Drawable drawable = itemImage.getDrawable();

    Bitmap picture = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    picture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

    final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/png");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, picture);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
}
```

Comment: *I added code to compress my Bitmap* ... no, you don't as you can't  ... you save/compress Bitmap to a stream which you never use it again ... and Bitmap will always take `width * heigth * bytes_per_pixel` memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM), `EXTRA_STREAM` is:

> A content: URI holding a stream of data associated with the Intent, used with ACTION_SEND to supply the data being sent.

You do not put a `Bitmap` into `EXTRA_STREAM` for an `image/png` `ACTION_SEND` request. You put a `Uri` pointing to a PNG into `EXTRA_STREAM`. Ideally, you do that via `FileProvider`, though if your `targetSdkVersion` is below 24, you can get away with `Uri.fromFile()` for the time being.